Set Xcode project Versioning System from the command line
I currently have a project using CircleCI and Fastlane. It is a Cordova mobile project that I want to automate the build number incrementing from Fastlane using
increment_build_number(
  build_number: app_store_build_number(
    initial_build_number: 1,
    version: get_version_number(xcodeproj: "...myproject.xcodeproj"),
    live: false
  ) + 1,
)

When running the job in CircleCI it give an error at this step: "Apple Generic Versioning is not enabled in this project."
CircleCI runs a step that creates a fresh iOS platform to make sure it is clean and therefore the settings may be defaulted again. Though I have attempted to run without it creating a new one while manually setting the versioning_system variable myself and it still gives the same error.
Is there a way to set Versioning System to Apple Generic from a command since I do not have access to Xcode within CircleCI's job?

I found in the jumble of logs: "There are no Xcode project files in this directory.  agvtool needs a project to operate."
I realized I was in the wrong directory for the command to automatically set the build number.
